# How to check whether any of the string present in the string using preg match?

Tags: php, timezone, preg-match

I want to segregate the china time zones  and other rest of the time zones separately 
so thought of using preg match

The idea what i thought is

$pattern = array("Asia/Shanghai", "Asia/Harbin" , "Asia/Chongqing" , "Asia/Urumqi");

$time_zone = "Asia/Chennai";

so what i want is

```
pregmatch($pattern, $time_zone){
    //china time_zone do some operation
}
else{
    //rest of the world time zone do some operation.
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `in_array()` ?

Comment: @Mani is my answer correct? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your pattern should be like:

```
preg_match("/(Asia\/Shanghai)?(Asia\/Harbin)?(Asia\/Chongqing)?(Asia\/Urumqi)?/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/f5N

EDIT: Sorry, I see that I used the wrong timezone in the phpliveregex page. Just replace the $input_line with the correct timezone.

EDIT2: thought I should type it out as you did in the question:

```
$time_zone = "Asia/Chennai";

If(pregmatch("/(Asia\/Shanghai)?(Asia\/Harbin)?(Asia\/Chongqing)?(Asia\/Urumqi)?/", $time_zone)){
    //rest of the world time zone do some operation.
}
else{
    //china time_zone do some operation        
}
```